# jQuery UI draggable/sortable not working in jsFiddle

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable, jsfiddle

I'm trying to run [this example](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable) in jsFiddle.

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/bJpyU/) is what I have now:

- `<html>`, `<head>` etc. are removed
- script put into script window
- CSS that was in `<style>` put into style window
- CSS from `<link>` put into resources (also tried CSS from CDN, as answer for other questions suggested, but nothing changed)

Error I get is `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'sortable'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in jsFiddle, I've reported it already.

You can fix that the following way:

- **do not** include jQuery UI under `Frameworks & Extensions` tab
- include both CSS and JS for jQuery UI from [CDN](http://codeorigin.jquery.com/ui/) under `External Resources` tab

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bJpyU/1/).

**EDIT**
I've discovered that only using 'edge' (2.x or 1.x) versions of jQuery causes this issue.
[Original example working with other jQuery version](http://jsfiddle.net/bJpyU/2/).